# How To Create a PHP Script to Send This One Data-uses PHP Fopen?

Tags: php, xml, soap, fopen

We have a page at work that doesn't appear to be working after a PHP upgrade.  Instead of having to go through the web sites forms to fill out to test this I wanted a script that I can launch from a web page that will send it the data just by clicking on the page.  It's a SOAP xml that it's parsing.  But at least if the script has the basics to send then data then I can mock up the XML to send to it.  At least this way I can put debugging code to see what is and is not executing correctly in the rest of the code.

```
$incoming_soap = @fopen('php://input', 'r');

if($incoming_soap)
{   
    while(!feof($incoming_soap))
    {       
        $string = fread($incoming_soap, 1024);          
        if(is_string($string))
        {           
            $incoming_fire_order_request .= $string         
        }       
    }

    fclose($incoming_soap); 
}
```

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Are there any errors in the error log?

Comment: No, unfortunately not a single one.   That's why I'm going to mock up data to pass to this script and then debug it through or make it start logging.  It was written by a vendor and stopped working after our company upgraded PHP.    So actually if I find where it's failing it might point me to other areas that aren't writing out XML files too.  I did create a simple PHP script so I know it's not any security settings not allowing it to create and write XML files.  So it's something before that process.

Comment: Make sure to remove error suppression from `@fopen`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the vendor, either through some upgrade or whatever had a blacklist setup so that nothing outside the site could call the Soap calls.  After they added our other domains into the whitelist it worked.